# Magento 2.3.2 CE Inconsistent stock status. "In Stock" when OOS and vice versa

Tags: magento2.3, quantity, stock-status, magento-community

I am having some odd inconsistencies with Magento 2.3.2 when it comes to "Quantity_and_Stock_Status".
I would like to add this to my layered navigation so customers can filter out the OOS but it is misreporting some items as OOS when they are in stock and vice versa.

[image]

As you can see from this image, the highlighted item is OOS but is showing as 'In Stock'. I have checked the product details, and it is marked as OOS, so I don't why the stock status is this way. You can also see five items at the bottom that are in stock, but stock status says they aren't. All product details are correct an marked as 'In Stock'. Does anybody know why this may be happening?

I am running in Production, and have reindexed several times.

Any pointers would be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: There must be some place where we can code something similar to this manually -  if(qty>0) echo "in stock"; else echo "out of stock"; - I just given the hint, sorry i don't know the actual answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's not that I need to show In stock/Out of stock on items. That is actually working fine. It's the 'quantity_and_stock_status' attribute that is tied into the layered navigation that is misfiring. I have 319 items that are incorrectly 'in stock' or 'out of stock' according to that. My image above is just a report I ran in Magento so I could see how many were incorrect.

Comment: May you please share the coding related files like your xml file or phtml files, so that we can trace the flow or any error message.

Comment: Which particular files would pertain to this error? I wouldn't think that it's phtml or xml, as it's some value that stored somewhere. Isn't it more likely to be an error in the database somewhere? But I don't know where to start looking.